# New Windows 7 workstation shows KSOD and extreme sluggishness; what gives?

Tags: windows-7, performance

I have been setting up a Windows 7 workstation:

- 4 GB RAM
- 1 TB SATA hard disk
- Core2 Duo CPU
- Intel GPU of quite recent make
- Windows 7 SP1 64-bit

About 1/3 of the times it boots up, it never reaches the login screen. Instead it shows a completely black screen with a cursor. The cursor responds to mouse movement, but there are no menus, and no response to keyboard input. I believe this is popularly known as the "black screen of death" or KSOD.

It also is extremely slow when it does complete the boot, and I am unable to figure out why. Process Explorer takes about 30 seconds to launch, for instance. There is no heavy disk activity, no high CPU usage, no unusual memory consumption; all drivers are installed, all devices are recognized, the Windows installation is brand new, and as far as I can tell there's no malware on it.

What are some probable causes, and how can I troubleshoot this thing further?

Comment: You say it's a "new" workstation, yet it has a Core2 Duo CPU?  Exactly how "New" is this machine?  Has it ever worked right? When you say "it shows a completely black screen with a cursor. The cursor responds to mouse movement", do you mean it's showing an actual [cursor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursor_(computing)), or a mouse [pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(graphical_user_interfaces))?  Test the disk(s). Ensure the PSU is providing enough power. Check for physical damage on the motherboard, etc.

Comment: Oh, and try booting into Safe Mode.

Comment: I would try swapping SATA cable and try a dif. SATA port on the mobo.